# How to shuffle an array giving the most space between the same object property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array for example:

```
[{name: "foo"},{name: "foo"}, {name: "foo"}, {name: "bar"}, {name: "bar"}, {name: "qux"}, {name: "corge"}, {name: "grault"}]
```

It needs to keep the best distance possible between the same elements, it does need to be always the same distance, but as far as possible

```
[{name: "foo"},{name: "bar"},{name: "qux"},{name: "foo"},{name: "corge"},{name: "grault"},{name: "foo"},{name: "bar"}]
```

attempts:

```js
var _ = _.noConflict();

let data = [
  {
    competitor: "Patrícia Gregório"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Patrícia Gregório"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Erika Eleuterio Salim Ali"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Mariani aparecida da Silva"
  },
  {
    competitor: "NATALIA TELLES SCHMIDT"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Tamila Cavalcante Castilho"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Heloísa Brasil dos Santos"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Rafaele Caraça"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Luana Aparecida"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Camila Vieira Carvalho de Souza"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Kemylli Quarties"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Amanda Polli"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Carolina Marques Figueiredo"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Marcelle Conceição Pereira Longo"
  },
  {
    competitor: "MICAELLA FERNANDES FRANÇA DA SILVA"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Liv landin"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Maria Eduarda Rossi Krieck"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Isabella Guimarães Pinto Costa"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Alessandra Esposito de Castro Cardoso"
  },
  {
    competitor: "FERNANDA FERNANDES DE CARVALHO"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Maria Eduarda Miranda"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Beatriz Macedo"
  },
  {
    competitor: "CARLA AMANDA DE OLIVEIRA"
  },
  {
    competitor: "eduarda cavalcante"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Amanda Chítero Silva"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Livia Rodrigues Lopes"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Priscila Sequeira"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Keila Pacheco"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Damaris Trindade"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Priscila Sequeira"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Fabiana Fernandes"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Carolina lois soares de Arruda"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Pollyanna Guratti"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Bruna Vieira"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Beatriz Delgado de Oliveira"
  },
  {
    competitor: "KELLY MOREIRA"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Fernanda Suzuki de Carvalho"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Keila Pacheco"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Mariana Moreira de Oliveira"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Angelita da Silva Rezende Vieira"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Rogéria da Silva Rezende"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Anna Laura Rodrigues dos Santos"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Maria Heloysa Xavier dos Santos"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Vanessa Gonçalves"
  },
  {
    competitor: "CARMEM SOARES FONSECA CAETANO"
  },
  {
    competitor: "DEBORA GAMA LIMA"
  },
  {
    competitor: "DARLENE DINIZ"
  },
  {
    competitor: "VITORIA PASCOAL DE SOUSA SANTOS"
  },
  {
    competitor: "GLAYCIE EVELYN MENDONÇA"
  },
  {
    competitor: "MARIANA MENEZES"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Julia Carvalho"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Isabela Tidioli"
  },
  {
    competitor: "PIETRA MACIEL"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Ana Simões"
  },
  {
    competitor: "PIETRA MACIEL"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Priscila Sequeira"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Jéssica Rosa"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Patrícia Gregório"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Patrícia Gregório"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Erika Eleuterio Salim Ali"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Mariani aparecida da Silva"
  },
  {
    competitor: "NATALIA TELLES SCHMIDT"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Tamila Cavalcante Castilho"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Heloísa Brasil dos Santos"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Rafaele Caraça"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Luana Aparecida"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Camila Vieira Carvalho de Souza"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Kemylli Quarties"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Amanda Polli"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Carolina Marques Figueiredo"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Marcelle Conceição Pereira Longo"
  },
  {
    competitor: "MICAELLA FERNANDES FRANÇA DA SILVA"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Liv landin"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Maria Eduarda Rossi Krieck"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Isabella Guimarães Pinto Costa"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Alessandra Esposito de Castro Cardoso"
  },
  {
    competitor: "FERNANDA FERNANDES DE CARVALHO"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Maria Eduarda Miranda"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Beatriz Macedo"
  },
  {
    competitor: "CARLA AMANDA DE OLIVEIRA"
  },
  {
    competitor: "eduarda cavalcante"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Amanda Chítero Silva"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Livia Rodrigues Lopes"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Priscila Sequeira"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Keila Pacheco"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Damaris Trindade"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Priscila Sequeira"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Fabiana Fernandes"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Carolina lois soares de Arruda"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Pollyanna Guratti"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Bruna Vieira"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Beatriz Delgado de Oliveira"
  },
  {
    competitor: "KELLY MOREIRA"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Fernanda Suzuki de Carvalho"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Keila Pacheco"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Mariana Moreira de Oliveira"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Angelita da Silva Rezende Vieira"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Rogéria da Silva Rezende"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Anna Laura Rodrigues dos Santos"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Maria Heloysa Xavier dos Santos"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Vanessa Gonçalves"
  },
  {
    competitor: "CARMEM SOARES FONSECA CAETANO"
  },
  {
    competitor: "DEBORA GAMA LIMA"
  },
  {
    competitor: "DARLENE DINIZ"
  },
  {
    competitor: "VITORIA PASCOAL DE SOUSA SANTOS"
  },
  {
    competitor: "GLAYCIE EVELYN MENDONÇA"
  },
  {
    competitor: "MARIANA MENEZES"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Julia Carvalho"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Isabela Tidioli"
  },
  {
    competitor: "PIETRA MACIEL"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Ana Simões"
  },
  {
    competitor: "PIETRA MACIEL"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Priscila Sequeira"
  },
  {
    competitor: "Jéssica Rosa"
  }
];


const spreadOrder = (array) => {
  var temp = [],
    count = {};

  for (let v of array) {
    if (!count[v.competitor]) count[v.competitor] = 0;
    if (!temp[count[v.competitor]]) temp[count[v.competitor]] = [];
    temp[count[v.competitor]].push(v);
    count[v.competitor]++;
  }
  let biggestCount = 0;
  let sorted = _.flatMap(temp, (array) =>
    array.sort((a, b) => {
      if (Math.abs(count[a.competitor] - count[b.competitor]) > biggestCount)
        biggestCount =
          count[b.competitor] > biggestCount
            ? count[b.competitor]
            : biggestCount;
      return count[b.competitor] - count[a.competitor];
    })
  );

  sortedCompare = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sorted));

  if (biggestCount > 1) {
    let ofCounter = 0;

    for (let i = sorted.length - biggestCount; i < sorted.length; i++) {
      let newIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i - 1));
      const sortedNow =
        sortedCompare[newIndex].competitor == sortedCompare[i].competitor;
      let sortedBefore = false;
      if (newIndex > 0)
        sortedBefore =
          sortedCompare[newIndex - 1].competitor == sortedCompare[i].competitor;

      const sortedAfter =
        sortedCompare[newIndex + 1].competitor == sortedCompare[i].competitor;
      if (
        (sortedNow || sortedBefore || sortedAfter) &&
        ofCounter <= sorted.length
      ) {
        i--;
        ofCounter++;
      } else {
        let changedContent = sorted[newIndex];
        sorted[newIndex] = sorted[i];
        sorted[i] = changedContent;
        let changedContentCompare = sortedCompare[newIndex];
        sortedCompare[newIndex] = sortedCompare[i];
        sortedCompare[i] = changedContentCompare;

        sortedCompare = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sorted));
      }
    }
  }

  return sorted;
};

const shuffle = (array) => {
  let currentIndex = array.length,
    temporaryValue,
    randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {
    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
};

const spreadOrder2 = (array) => {
  var temp = [],
    count = {};

  for (let v of array) {
    if (!count[v.competitor]) count[v.competitor] = 0;
    if (!temp[count[v.competitor]]) temp[count[v.competitor]] = [];
    temp[count[v.competitor]].push(v);
    count[v.competitor]++;
  }

  for (let i = 1; i < temp.length; i++) {
    if (temp[i].length > 3) {
      const lastComp = temp[i - 1][temp[i - 1].length - 1];
      for (let j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        if (lastComp.competitor === temp[i][j].competitor) spreadOrder2(array);
      }
    }
  }

  const flat = temp.flat();

  return flat;
};

const newTry = (array) => {
  for (let i = 2; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
    if (array[i - 2].competitor._id == array[i].competitor._id) {
      let buffer = array[i + 1];
      array[i + 1] = array[i];
      array[i] = buffer;
    } else if (array[i - 1].competitor._id == array[i].competitor._id) {
      let buffer = array[i + 1];
      array[i + 1] = array[i];
      array[i] = buffer;
    }
  }
  for (let i = array.length - 3; i > 0; i--) {
    if (array[i + 2].competitor._id == array[i].competitor._id) {
      let buffer = array[i - 1];
      array[i - 1] = array[i];
      array[i] = buffer;
    } else if (array[i + 1].competitor._id == array[i].competitor._id) {
      let buffer = array[i - 1];
      array[i - 1] = array[i];
      array[i] = buffer;
    }
  }
  return array;
};

Array.prototype.unique = function () {
  var i = 0,
    t = 1,
    l = (this.length >>> 0) - 1;
  for (; i < l; t = ++i + 1)
    while ((t = this.indexOf(this[i], t)) !== -1) this.splice(t, 1);
  return this;
};
Array.prototype.count = function (item) {
  var i = 0,
    t = 0;
  while ((i = this.indexOf(item, i) + 1)) t++;
  return t;
};
Array.prototype.remove = function (item) {
  var i = this.indexOf(item);
  if (i !== -1) this.splice(i, 1);
  return this;
};

function shuffleArray(array, previous) {
  if (!array.length) return array;
  // The list of unique items in the array
  var univals = array.slice().unique(),
    idx,
    pivot,
    rest;
  if (previous != null)
    // The array can't start with the previous element
    univals.remove(previous);

  while (univals.length) {
    // We choose an element from the possible ones
    idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * univals.length);
    pivot = univals[idx];
    // We try to shuffle the rest of the array.
    rest = shuffleArray(array.slice().remove(pivot), pivot);
    // If we got a shuffled array, we're done.
    // Else, we remove our pivot element from the possible ones
    if (rest != null) return [pivot].concat(rest);
    else univals.splice(idx, 1);
  }
  return null;
}

function insertNextItem(list, item) {
  // special case an empty items array
  if (list.length === 0) {
    list.push(item);
    return true;
  }

  // build an array of possible insertion positions
  // items.length + 1 means to add it at the end
  var possiblePositions = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length + 1; i++) {
    possiblePositions.push(i);
  }

  // select random position, see if that is allowed
  // if not, remove it from the possibilities and select a new random position
  while (possiblePositions.length > 0) {
    var randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * possiblePositions.length);
    var pos = possiblePositions[randIndex];
    // check if this position is allowed
    if (list[pos] !== item && (pos === 0 || list[pos - 1] !== item)) {
      // position is allowed, insert it and return
      list.splice(pos, 0, item);
      return true;
    } else {
      // was not allowed, so remove this possiblePositions choice
      // and let the loop try again
      possiblePositions.splice(randIndex, 1);
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function buildList(sourceItems, num) {
  var items = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    insertNextItem(
      items,
      sourceOfItems[Math.floor(Math.random() * sourceOfItems.length)]
    );
  }
  return items;
}


// Testing
console.log(data.map((x) => x.competitor));
let countAll = 0;
// testing 1000 times
for(let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
data = shuffle(data);
data = spreadOrder(data);
// counting repeated value
const count = data.filter((obj, index) =>
data[index - 1] != null ? obj.competitor === data[index - 1].competitor : false).length;
// if repeated value, add 1 to countAll
if(count > 0) countAll++;
}
// show how many tests has repeated values closest to 0 is better 
console.log(countAll);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

and it cannot be like that:

```
 [{name: "foo"}, {name: "bar"}, {name: "qux"}, {name: "corge"}, {name: "grault"},{name: "foo"}, {name: "bar"}, {name: "foo"}]
```

this wrong example is repeating the repeated names at the end of the array, it needs to keep distance for at least 2 elements if possible

Comment: So what is your attempt?

Comment: to spread the array giving the most distance between the elements

Comment: We know what your goal is, but what have you tried? Have you put in any research effort?

Comment: I added my attempts, all the things that i've been testing

Comment: You have to find the elements that occur most often and count them, e.g. in 1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6 the elements 2 and 3 occur twice. Move these elements to the front then all other element and again these elements in the same order. That gives you 2,3,1,4,5,6,2,3. If elements occur more often you have to evenly distribute them in the array.